# Building game off youtube tutorial: They use circular tiles on the canvas, I would like to use squares, how do I achieve this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

I have been following this tutorial on how to build snake on android studio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPlG7ra83lo

He uses circles that build up a 28*42 box that looks like this:

[image: Example of circular grid]

I was hoping to replace these circles with squares but when I try various methods such as this:

```
canvas.drawRect(x*tileSizeX,tileSizeY*x,tileSizeY*y, x, mPaint);
```

I end up with an output like this:

[image: My attempt]

Below is the code used in the SnakeView class:

```
public class SnakeView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private TileType snakeViewMap[][];
    public SnakeView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setSnakeViewMap (TileType[][] map){
        this.snakeViewMap = map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (snakeViewMap != null) {
            float tileSizeX = canvas.getWidth()/snakeViewMap.length;
            float tileSizeY = canvas.getHeight() / snakeViewMap[0].length;

            float circleSize = Math.min(tileSizeX, tileSizeY) /2;

            for (int x=0; x < snakeViewMap.length; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y <snakeViewMap[x].length; y++) {
                    switch (snakeViewMap[x][y]) {

                    case Nothing:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                    case Wall:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case SnakeHead:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case SnakeTail:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case Apple:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    }
                    canvas.drawRect(x*tileSizeX,tileSizeY*x,tileSizeY*y, x, mPaint);
                    //canvas.drawCircle(x * tileSizeX + tileSizeX/2f + circleSize/2, y * tileSizeY + tileSizeY/2f + circleSize/2, circleSize, mPaint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas

this is the parameters for circle
    void drawCircle (float cx, 
                float cy, 
                float radius, 
                Paint paint)

where

```
cx  float: The x-coordinate of the center of the cirle to be drawn
cy  float: The y-coordinate of the center of the cirle to be drawn
radius  float: The radius of the cirle to be drawn
paint   Paint: The paint used to draw the circle
This value must never be null.
```

and

drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)

so your also will need to change somewhat

instead of

```
 canvas.drawRect(
      x*tileSizeX, //LEFT
      tileSizeY*x, //TOP
      tileSizeY*y, //RIGHT
      x,           //BOTTOM 
      mPaint);
```

you need to offset your values such that it is in the order of

> left, top, right bottom

```
left:  x*tileSizeX
top :  y*tileSizeY
right :  x*tileSizeX +(circleSize*2) //we want the diameter instead of radius
bottom:  y*tileSizeY +(circleSize*2)
```